# How to speed up datatables plugin using a form?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, datatables

I'm using datatables plugin to display the table data.
Everything was working find until the table got more records 12k to be exact. Now its super slow and I usually have to 'stop script'.
What I have its a form, from this form I can change what is display in the table depending on what specific data I want to get. This was working fine before adding more records to table.

First I display all the records in the table, when user submits the form it changes the records return from table.

What could I do to speed the process?

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
        "aLengthMenu": [[10,25, 50, 75,100, -1], [10,25, 50, 75,100, "All"]],
    "pageLength": 1000

    } );
} );

</script>

<form  name="fraud_view"    action="" method="post">
      <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" ></td>
</form>

<cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "submit")>


<cfquery datasource="test" name="Get_data">
  SELECT * FROM tablename
  where 1 = 1  ect...
<cfelse>
  <cfquery datasource="test" name="Get_data">
select *
from tablename
order by date desc
</cfquery>

</cfif>  
<!--- here im displaying the table date --->
<table id="example" class="display " cellspacing="1" width="100%">
        <tbody>
          <cfoutput query="Get_data">
              </td>
                <td>#account_num#</td>
                <td>#first_name#</td>
                <td>more columns</td>
            </tr>
            </cfoutput>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Are you saying your filtering script is running too slow or the general datatables loading is too slow?

Comment: You are overwhelming your browser with too much data.  Presenting 12,000 rows of data to review and edit might have a similar effect on the person.

Comment: You can use server side processing for datatables along with pagination.

Comment: @ChrisH. the datatables loading its too slow

Comment: For Server side processing see: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

Comment: Another option is to avoid having the browser having to render a 12,000+ row table. There's a datatables option to pass your data as JavaScript (JSON)  data, then have it paginate through it. That way it only has to render the rows as they are displayed.

Answer (score 4):

Like some of the comments have already mentioned, you may want to check out the [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) option (this example uses a PHP script but you could use any server-side backend  you want). The basic idea is that instead of having the jQuery and JavaScript code handle things like pagination, sorting, searching, etc. client-side you can have that handling be done on the server in a much faster language, and then just return the results.

For example, let's say you wanted to filter results (doesn't matter how) and get the first 10%. If you don't use server-side, all that processing and filtering has to be done by the plugin, and it has to process all 12k rows. If instead you use server-side processing, you tell the server you want the top 10%, and then it *only shows you* those values that result, meaning that the plugin only has to handle 1200 rows instead of 12,000.

This can be tricky to do if you're not as familiar with the server-side language, but one option is to use the .NET or PHP libraries developed by the author (located [here](https://editor.datatables.net/manual/net/) and [here](https://editor.datatables.net/manual/php/), respectively). These do require a license to the Editor extension, however, which is not free, but does add a lot of nice features to DataTables.

If you want to develop your own server-side code, check out [this](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) documentation page which outlines what it needs to do and how it needs to do it. It may be a little bit more complicated, but it will drastically improve the speed of your DataTables.

Answer (score 1):

Server side datatables is most likely the best option (as others have mentioned) but does come with obvious drawbacks such as having to re-load the data for every request e.g. filtering, sorting, editing etc as well as being a lot more complicated to set up.

If server side is not possible then your best bet is to just reduce the amount of data on display at one time.

I am assuming you are displaying a lot of data per row as i have managed to have slow loading but working data tables at 30k rows on an ajax datasource (which should still need to load all the data as html does).

Cutting columns is one possibility but also if you only need some of the data less often (e.g. long text descriptions) implementing ajax based (or html5 data attribute based) child rows can be good to cut down columns and then show the more bulky data when needed on a per row basis https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html .

Also you could implement your own filters on the data before it is rendered to the page (sometimes you dont actually need to see all of the large dataset all the time)